# Cython: how to disable debug symbols

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython

I use this code:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize


if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup(ext_modules=cythonize(f"some_module.pyx"))
```

And I run it from the command line like this:

```
python build.py build_ext --inplace
```

If there was any error in the code, then the line number, module and function (if the error is inside it) will be indicated in the error text.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SLLMK\Desktop\Test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import some_module
  File "some_module.pyx", line 18, in init some_module
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

How can I disable the display of this data?

OS: Windows.